# Lagged Fibonacci generator using a discarding strategy

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, shuffle

I am trying to implement the Lagged Fibonacci generator but using a discarding strategy. I have these guidelines to follow:

Step 1: Return random numbers from the next 127 numbers generated from your RNG

Step 2: Discard the next 997 numbers generated from your RNG

Step 3: Goto Step 1.

The problem is sometimes the values generated are bopping up an error with regards to array out of bounds in section 'int randomNumber = array[Next(127)];'

The initial values are:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] array = new int[6000];
int j = 83;
static int k = 258;
int m = 2;
int n = k;
double randomNumber = 0;
```

Here is the code for the Discarding Method:

```
public int NextUsingDiscarding(int maxValue)
{
    try
    {
        int[] array = new int[127];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Next(maxValue);
        }

        int randomNumber = array[Next(127)];

        for (int i = 0; i < 127 + 997; i++)
        {
            Next(maxValue);
        }

        return randomNumber;
    }
    catch
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and the number generator:

```
public int Next(int maxValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(maxValue);
    }

    int firstElement = array[n - j];
    int secondElement = array[n - k];

    randomNumber = (firstElement + secondElement) % Math.Pow(m, 32);

    array[n] = (int)randomNumber;

    return (int)randomNumber % (maxValue + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Next` returns a value between 0 and `maxvalue`, which as called here is 127.  But your array has indices between 0 and 126.

Comment: Seriously?  You need a value between 0 and 126; `Next(n)` returns values between 0 and *n*.